# Hacer una tabla con arrays en Java

Tags: java, array, tablas

pues estoy tratando de hacer la siguiente tabla en java:
[image: .]

Y la verdad no sé cómo, estoy haciendo un código basándome en algunos códigos que he encontrado, pero no consigo que funcione. Lo más que he logrado es que muestre las cantidades, pero aparecen verticalmente.
Esto es lo que llevo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\tEne-Feb-Mar\tAbr-May-Jun\tJul-Ago-Sep\tOct-Nov-Dic");
        System.out.println("\nChocolate\nVainilla\nFresa\nOreo");
        int ing[][]={{111,483,471,427},{192,500,355,158},{289,470,474,160},{415,114,161,308}};
                display(ing);
    }
    public static void display(int x[][]){

        for (int fila=0;fila<x.length;fila++){
            for (int columna=0;columna<x[fila].length;columna++){
                System.out.println(x[fila][columna]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar :). Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un detalle dentro del segundo for
`System.out.println(x[fila][columna]+"\t");` utilizas `println` es decir que luego de imprimir hace un salto de linea.

Ademas los sabores deben ser impresos dentro del primer `for` para ir agregando fina a fila.

Para solucionar agregue `String sabores[]={"\nChocolate", "\nVainilla", "\nFresa\t", "\nOreo\t"};`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("\tEne-Feb-Mar\tAbr-May-Jun\tJul-Ago-Sep\tOct-Nov-Dic");
    String sabores[]={"\nChocolate", "\nVainilla", "\nFresa\t", "\nOreo\t"};
    int ing[][]={{111,483,471,427},{192,500,355,158},{289,470,474,160},{415,114,161,308}};
    display(ing, sabores);
}
public static void display(int x[][], String sabores[]){

    for (int fila=0;fila<x.length;fila++){
        System.out.print(sabores[fila]+"\t");
        for (int columna=0;columna<x[fila].length;columna++){
            System.out.print(x[fila][columna]+"\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
    Ene-Feb-Mar Abr-May-Jun Jul-Ago-Sep Oct-Nov-Dic

Chocolate   111     483     471     427     

Vainilla    192     500     355     158     

Fresa       289     470     474     160     

Oreo        415     114     161     308
```

ejemplo corriendo -> https://rextester.com/FFOWU20053